# how to set the limit of maxresults upto permissible limit of youtube data api in python?

Tags: python, youtube-data-api, youtube-api

I created this script to extract all playlist video info from a youtube channel in python but due to quota limit I'm unable to extract more than 10k videos info. How to set the limit to less than 10k or any other method to extract info?

This is my code:

```
while 1:
    res = youtube.playlistItems().list(playlistId=playlist_id,\
            part='id,snippet',maxResults=50,pageToken=next_page_token).execute()
    next_page_token = res.get('nextPageToken')
    if next_page_token is None:
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One can use the counter to come out of the loop. Always keep in mind that calculate the quota for any kind of search. Yes its a bad thing to having 10K limit but anyhow one can extract atleast till 10k. Ex: a youtube.search.list with will incur cost as 5 per page.

```
count =1
...loop starts
then code
if count and next page response is not none
increment count
else 
break
...
```